# jquery: How to select nested radio element

Tags: jquery

HTML Code :

```
<div class="poll_all_chs" >
            {% for ch in poll_obj.get_choices %}
                <div class="poll_ch">
                    <span><input type="radio" id="radio_button" name="choice_id" value="{{ch.id}}">{{ch.choice}}</span>
                </div>
</div>
```

i want to check the state of radio button using jquery like

```
if(radio_ele).is(':checked')) { 
                        bool =  true
                }
```

But 
 how can i access radio button element ?

Comment: It looks as if you are dynamically creating elements with the same ID. This is very bad practice and makes your HTML Invalid, please make the  IDs Unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')){
   //code here for checked 
}
```

Use below code

Id must be unique. Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

```
if($('input:radio[name="choice_id"]').is(':checked')){
   //code here for checked 
}
```

or

```
$('input:radio[name="choice_id"]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked){
       //code here for checked 
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd assume it's because the OP is adding more than one control with the same ID, would this solution still work for that?

Comment: i'm adding radio button in a loop, such case how can i assign different ids for radio button

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".poll_ch span :radio").each(function() {
    if (this.checked)
        console.log("Im checked!");
});
```

Also, an important note, you're going to have repeating ID's with the code you provided. Fix that, it's all around bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".poll_ch :radio").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==true)
        console.log("This radio checked");
});
```